# Backbone getting attributes from a model in a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need help in trying to get attributes out of my model with [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

**Below is what I have tried so far.** I connect to a REST URL and pull back data in json. I now want to display some of that data within the view. However, when I try print/console out `club_url` I get an undefined error. If I print out the `test` object itself I can see the value in the `attributes section` of the object.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
(function ($) {
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/test/',
        initialize: function () {
            this.club_url = this.club_url
        }
    });
    var thisCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/test/',
        model: Model
    });
    var PanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#reward_view',
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection = new thisCollection();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            var test = new thisCollection;
            test.fetch();
            console.log(test.get('club_url'))
            return this;
        }
    });
    var listView = new PanelView();
})(jQuery);
```

**As another test I tried was to init something like this in the view**

```
        this.model = new Model()
        this.model.fetch()
```

but then in the render function I did this:

```
this.model.get('club_url')
```

however this did not work either!

Comment: If I'm just trying to get one object then should I not get the model only not the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetching of data is async operation. So, I guess that you should wait for an event before to get `club_url`. I.e. something like that:

```
render: function () {
    var test = new thisCollection;
    test.fetch({
        success: function(collection, response) {
            console.log(test.get('club_url'))
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Would this not be done in the initialize function of the view?

Comment: Also as it just a model not a collection i.e. one object, should I be using collection? See update above. thanks

Comment: Yes to both questions.